# DataMember vs DataMemberAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datamember

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchResults
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<SearchDetail> PList { get; set; }
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

The metadata for `DataMember` and `DataMemberAttribute` are same.

Is 'DataMember' just an alias of the other? Which one should we be using? (If possible please provide a link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the 'Attribute' on the attribute name is optional. Use whatever makes you happy.

[Attributes on MSDN (See the Note 2/3rd's down)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/48zeb25s(v=vs.90))

> #### Note
>
> By convention, all attribute names end with the word "Attribute" to distinguish them from other items in the .NET Framework. However, you do not need to specify the attribute suffix when using attributes in code. For example, [DllImport] is equivalent to [DllImportAttribute], but DllImportAttribute is the attribute's actual name in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4):

> By convention, all attribute names end with Attribute. However, several languages that target the runtime, such as Visual Basic and C#, do not require you to specify the full name of an attribute. For example, if you want to initialize System.ObsoleteAttribute, you only need to reference it as Obsolete.

Source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/applying-attributes

It is same and for all the [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) in .Net Framework it is applicable. Ex. Serializable

Comment: The convention is to name the class with the "Attribute" appended, but in usage to omit it.

Comment: @rkaregaran: could you provide an official link to your comment statement. I tried google but it's no help (or maybe it late :P). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any attribute with the ending *-Attribute* in .NET, i.e. to use the full name of the attribute type. Just to keep it simple, the ending is allowed to be omitted.